# AWS Avoiding Duplicates in East and West SNS triggered lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

We basically want to create an active passive setup without being active passive. So all aws services must be replicated in both regions. But routing can be different. Flow Currently. SNS -> Lambda

We currently have a lambda triggered by an SNS after another process we cant control is completed. Active - Active east wand west. Each region has its own sns trigger triggering it. East does processing and west does processing separately and they each print a file.

Current issue is east & west are both processing and outputting copies of the same file. Any suggestions on how I can resolve this ideally in the aws space? So only one lambda is triggered.

- We need to have active active lambdas
- Thought of sns -> sqs -> lambda. But havent thought of how to get around the routing for having a copy in each region.
- Seems filtering can be done for sqs but can sqs policies talk to each other during this filtering?

Found an image thats a perfect depiction of what we have but what **I DONT WANT**. In the end I want only File 1 to send.
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgHAF.png)

Comment: You will need <something> that acts as an arbitrator of which system is the 'source of truth'. For example, the East system might be the 'source of truth' but when it becomes unavailable the West system becomes the source of truth. Both systems do equal processing, but the East system is the 'primary' system. The arbitrator should run in the non-primary Region and monitor the primary region for problems. However, it could have problems determining when a failure has happened because it might be caused by a network disconnection rather than a failure. The design for such a system is complex.

Comment: To @JohnRotenstein's point, this is ultimately impossible.  If there is a network issue *right after the Lambda is fired* and everything else is running perfectly you cannot know that.  You need to create a system that handles (eventual) duplicates.  Perhaps a different S3 key name and a business rule to handle duplicates.  Anything that relies on a perfect global locking/semaphore system is going to fail.